# Vector spaces, the complementary space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $F$ and $G$ be a subspaces of the vector space $E$ and $\dim(F)=\dim(G)$. Prove that there is a subspace $H$ that satisfies the following: $E=F\oplus H=G\oplus H$.

Comment: If there was only one subspace $F$, could you find $H$ so that $E=F\oplus H$?

Comment: Yes, if there is only one subspace F, the H would be the subspace that is generated by the vectors that complete the basis of F to the basis of E.

Comment: Can you figure out a way to amend the process of completing the basis so that you avoid things in $F$ and $G$ at each step?

Comment: I think that's possible if we can figure out a way to assign a complement to the subspace F or G of the finite vector space E. However, it must be remembered that the complement is not unique, e.g., in a vector space we find that if we have a vector space T with a dimension of 2 represented by plane vectors, then any vector space with dimension of 1 represented by a line that intersects the plane will be its complement.

Comment: @HussamAddinEzzo Supposing $E$ has finite dimension: Argue that if the dimension of $F,G$ is smaller than the dimesion of $E$ then $E\setminus(F\cup G)$ cannot be empty. If $F=G$ this is clear, else if $x\in F$ and $y\in G$ so that $y\not\in F$ and $x\not\in G$ then $x+y$ cannot be in $F$ or in $G$. Use this to find common elements to complete bases of $F,G$ to bases of $E$.